# Dolphin FIle Manager on Windows - Dark Theme

Tags: windows-10, color-theme, dark-mode, dolphin-file-manager

I am using [Dolphin File Manger](https://apps.kde.org/dolphin/) for obvious reasons (tabs, split views, remembers what's open, filters, functioning searches and tons others) on Windows and to this date I haven't been able to force it to use **dark theme**.

Since it's a KDE application (and in turn Qt), it's 100% possible to make it dark and it should be also pretty easy. I use Dolphin on Windows as "portable".

```
dolphin.exe --help-all
```

...contains also a list of Qt options, including `--platformtheme <theme>` option, which I would assume could be used to load a `qss` style sheet, so I downloaded [Dark Monokai](https://gist.github.com/Zren/2779042) and run dolphin as:

```
dolphin.exe --platformtheme C:\Users\myhome\Downloads\DarkMonokai.qss
```

...but still no luck, Dolphin is "white". My assumption might be wrong and I couldn't find any documentation for this option.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, still have a light theme :-( And still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. After a few hours of messing around with this, I was able to come up with a working solution.

### TL;DR

Apparently Dolphin needs to be run like this:

```
dolphin.exe --stylesheet C:\Users\USER\path\to\grey.qss --platform windows:darkmode=2
```

Where `grey.qss` needs to be placed in the given path.

`grey.qss`:

```css
QWidget {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
}
QScrollBar {
    background: rgb(42, 42, 42);
}
/* Context menu buttons. */
QMenu::item:selected {
    background: black;
}
/* Makes some cickable things in the configuration menu look nicer. */
QAbstractButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}
QAbstractButton:pressed {
    background-color: black;
}
/* Top menu bar buttons */
QToolButton {
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}
QToolButton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.505);
}
QToolButton:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(126, 126, 126);
}
QToolButton:checked {
    background-color: black;
}
QToolButton:selected {
    background-color: rgb(31, 28, 99);
}
```

### Explanation

Instead of `--platformtheme` the option `--stylesheet` needs to be used. There is no mention of it in `dolphin.exe --help-all`, but it seems to be a standard option for Qt applications.
With this option I was able to use the style as defined in an external `.qss` file. **However**, I wasn't able to find a way to change the color of some elements, namely the filename labels were still black just like they are in the light theme.

[Black filename label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHEsS.png)

So that's where the other option comes in: `--platform windows:darkmode=2`. This changes the color to white, allowing us to use a darker background.

Now at first I tried using the file `DarkMonokai.qss` as mentioned in the question, but it didn't work for me. Since it's very long and I had no idea what the issue might be, I went ahead and created my own minimal stylesheet `grey.qss`. It's nothing special, but gets the job done giving us a dark theme.

In order to be as reproducible as possible, [this](https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Dolphin_Release_win64/2022/) is the Dolphin build I used.

Here is what my Dolphin looks with that stylesheet. Again, it's nothing special, but at least it doesn't burn my eyes.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApTmd.png)

### Improve

I also made a [git repository](https://github.com/Bleskocvok/dolpwin-dark) in case anyone wants to fork/contribute and improve the solution.

Comment: Awsome! Works as described, thank you! As the gray QSS is only an example, it is not a complete theme and I tried few others. Unfortunately as we found out, DarkMonokai or DarkSolarized QSS themes don't work at all, so I'll have to look for something else, or complete that gray.qss example...